# Can anyone identify this glassware?

Tags: equipment

Hoping for a little help identifying this lab glass , I don't know anything about lab glass , this was in a storage unit I'm purchased at auction,,, there is what I think is called a condense & 2 round beakers or flasks,, one is 50ml & the other is 200ml ,,, all the male & female connector are marked SJ GSA CO 28/15 ...PLEASE is there anything you can tell me about what there are called & what they would be used for. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

The glassware isn't particularly valuable. Finding someone who wants it will be the problem. If you were going to buy it new, I'm thinking maybe $150.

It is indeed a distillation setup. The large flask is the pot in which you'd put the stuff that you wanted to boil. The small flask would collect the stuff that you boil off. The nipples on the condenser are for rubber hoses to connect to a water supply so that the condenser jacket can be water cooled. Water goes in on the bottom and out on the top. In order to use this you're missing some parts.

- You need a couple of ringstands and clamps to hold the whole thing together.
- Two thermometers would go into the top of the condenser. One to monitor the pot temp, and the other to monitor the condensate temp.
- You need some metal clamps to hold the flasks to the condenser.
- You need something to heat the pot, a Bunsen burner would do.

Comment: Not looking to use it , As I said it was in a storage unit 
I purchased at auction , I buy to sell everything in the unit. Was just interested in finding out what it is so I know how what to call it when I try to sell it

Answer (score 4):

Careful - You are missing a distillation adapter between the condenser and the receiving flask. Without the adapter, the receiving flask should simply be placed under the end of the condenser to receive the distillate, rather than attached to it. Otherwise you would be heating a closed system, possibly leading to a catastrophic failure.

Comment: Good point that I failed to mention. It looked to me as if the thermometer holes are not ground glass. I assumed that there was a pressure exit there, but didn't mention that.

Comment: The joints are reminiscent of the Buchi ones for the receiver flask on a rotary evaporator under vacuum.  Could this be for vacuum distillation?

Comment: Not looking to use it , As I said it was in a storage unit 
I purchased at auction , I buy to sell everything in the unit. Was just interested in finding out what it is so I know how what to call it when I try to sell it